# Simple question about a closed interval in $\Bbb{R^2}$

Tags: general-topology, geometry

Let $I=[a,b]\times[c,d]\subset$$\Bbb{R^2}.$ How does one infer, that $$I=(a,c) + [0,b-a]\times[0,d-c]?$$

I find this odd, since these intervals do not seem to have the same area, since we are adding the open interval $(a,c)$ here. With some concrete numbers, I did find a few examples that do work, but I don't see where the generalization comes from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(a,c)$ doesn't mean an open interval there; it's referring to a point in $\mathbb R^2$.

And it's using the notation for adding an element to a set, where $x + A = \{x+a | a \in A \}$. This can be thought of, and is sometimes called, "shifting $A$ by $x$".

Basically,

$$(a,c) + ([0,b-a]\times[0,d-c])$$

can be read as "build a rectangle of the correct width, $(b-a)$, and height, $(d-c)$, at the origin, and then shift it so the lower left hand corner moves from $(0,0)$ to $(a,c)$". And this is the same as building it in place, i.e. $[a,b] \times [c,d]$.